# How to change code from retrofit to volley

Tags: android, retrofit, android-volley

I have this api request code in retrofit i want to send the request using volley
Everything is all right but i don't know what is the purpose of hasbody = true. And when i send request using volley it can't works. Kindly guide me how can i send request on this api using volley.

```
 @HTTP(method = "DELETE", path = "ad/delete/", hasBody = true)
    Call<ResponseBody> deleteMyAds(
            @Body JsonObject jsonObject,
            @HeaderMap Map<String, String> headers
    );
```

This is my volley function:

```
 private void deleteFromMyAdds(){

        final ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(mCntxt);
        progress.setTitle(mCntxt.getResources().getString(R.string.loading_t));
        progress.setMessage(mCntxt.getResources().getString(R.string.loading_t));
        progress.setCancelable(false); // disable dismiss by tapping outside of the dialog
        progress.show();
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCntxt);


        Map<String, String> params22 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params22.put("ad_id", Utils.ad_home_clicked);
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(params22);

        JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.DELETE, Utils.base_Url+"ad/delete/", jsonObject,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        Log.d("ResponseAdds :" , response.toString());
                        progress.dismiss();
                        MyPalmTreeFragment carsFragment = new MyPalmTreeFragment();
                        AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) mCntxt;
                        activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer,
                                carsFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                progress.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(mCntxt,mCntxt.getResources().getString(R.string.somethingwentwrong_t), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("Accept", "application/json");
                params.put("Authorization", Utils.user_token);
                params.put("Purchase-Code", "b638a7e5-d833-417e-b79c-c28050720738");
                params.put("custom-security", "11223344");
                params.put("Adforest-Lang-Locale", "en");
                params.put("Adforest-Request-From", "android");
                params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                params.put("Cache-Control", "max-age=640000");
                return params;
            }




        };

        queue.add(jsonRequest);
    }
```

Comment: That sounds like the opposite of what you should want to be doing, why do you need to swap out Retrofit for Volley?

Comment: better learn volley and try, then point us to your code.

Comment: I have to change it in volley compulsory because my whole project is in volley noit in retrofit